# Sent Form Data from View to Controller using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form and a save button. On click, I want to post all that data from the form to my `Controller` using Ajax. I could have done that using `Input::all()`, but I'm trying to avoid my page to **refresh**.

I want to be able to access those form data, just like `input::all()`, but using Ajax instead.

How would one go about and implement something like this ?

---

I've tried

**JS**

```
$('.saveRateLimitBTN').click(function (event) {

    var url = '{{env("APP_URL")}}{{$cpe_mac}}'+'/device/'+'{{$device_mac}}'+'/rate/update';

    var inputs = {};
    $("#editRateLimitForm :input").each(function() {
        inputs[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'PUT',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: inputs,
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('PUT error.', xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });

});
```

---

**DeviceController > updateRate()** function

```
public function updateRate(){

        dd('Here'); // This never get run.
}
```

---

**Route**

```
Route::put('{cpe_mac}/device/{device_mac}/rate/update',['as'=>'device.update', 'uses'=>'DeviceController@updateRate']);
```

---

**Form (Blade Syntax)**

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/'.$cpe_mac.'/device/'.$device_mac.'/rate/update', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' =>'form','method' => 'PUT', 'id' => 'editRateLimitForm')) !!}

        <span class="pull-left">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p>Downlink </p>
                <select type="text" id="rateDownSelect" class="form-control" name="max_down" >

                    @foreach ($rate_limit as $key => $value)
                    <option value="{{$value or ''}}"
                    >{{$value or ''}} Kbps</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p>Uplink</p>
                <select type="text" id="rateUpSelect" class="form-control" name="max_up" >
                    @foreach ($rate_limit as $key => $value)
                    <option value="{{$value or ''}}">{{$value or ''}} Kbps</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </span><br>


        {!! Form::hidden('cpe_mac', $cpe_mac)!!}
        {!! Form::hidden('device_mac', $device_mac)!!}



        <span class="pull-right">
            <button class="saveRateLimitBTN btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right" type="button">Save</button>
        </span>


{!! Form::close();!!}
```

---

**Result**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/000D6751560C/device/0800277B6BDE/rate/update. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 2):

Serialize the form like below to access all types of form field values.

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
  // Your Ajax here !
});
```

Useful URLs:
https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/
https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: I've tried `$( "#editRateLimitForm" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log( $( this ).serialize() ); // Nothing printing out 
    });` Nothing is printing out ! :(

Comment: do you have form tag first ? please share html code as well.

Comment: test by adding input type=submit button rather keeping button

Comment: Check the jsfiddle url - http://jsfiddle.net/0br4qcgg/1/ will see rest after 4 - 5 hours :) its 1.10 am here

Comment: Change the button to `type=submit`, I saw the serialize data now. How do I get them to spit out an array/object instead ?

Comment: I saw your fiddle, but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Please update your question with your expectation clearly its confusing the members

Comment: Do you know Laravel ?

Comment: I want to sent my form data from my view to my controller. You answered part of my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98132/discussion-between-ihue-and-alamelu-venkat).

Answer (score 1):

@ihue Instead of using `.serialize()` which I see you used in the other comments, use `.serializeArray()` to get the data object for your PUT request. But the other problem here, based on your error is that you can't send ajax requests from one domain to another domain.  It says you are on localhost:8888 and are sending request to localhost, which is a different domain.

Try changing the AJAX request to go to `http://localhost:8888/[yourURL]` instead of using the relative `/[yourURL]` and see if that makes a difference.

If that doesn't work you need to allow CORS (Cross-Origin Request Sharing) within your Laravel API. Here is some information about CORS http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ and here is a Laravel package to help take care of it https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: Thanks for updating, I will keep looking at your issue

Comment: see my edit - based on the error you're getting this is a CORS problem

Comment: Thank-you for your answer ! I'll try those suggestions now. My function in my controller doesn't seem to get execute. Do you know why ?

Answer (score 0):

You APP_URL is probably set to `http://localhost` but your application's current url is `http://localhost:8888` . Due to this, it is being treated as cross domain request for which you need to allow cross domain requests by adding this your htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Other solution, which you should ideally do is to change your AJAX url like this:

```
var url = '{{ url($cpe_mac."/device/".$device_mac."/rate/update") }}';
```

This will define the AJAX url using the url you are using currently to access your website.